The hidden icon arrow has disappeared from the taskbar
The hidden icons arrow has disappeared from the taskbar. it is not possible to hide the systray icons

Have you enabled: show all?

Right click the task bar to the left of where the arrow should be, then select Taskbar Settings:

Then click "Other system tray icons" and enable "Hidden icon menu".

You should have the ability to move icons to the hidden menu again. You can also use this area to choose which icons are hidden by default.
